# Android Studio Memory usage for foreground service

Tags: android, android-studio, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am finding memory leaks in my Foreground service that heavily uses BLE, and in trying to debug and find the leaks i was looking at the Memory Monitor in Android Studio and comparing the "allocated memory" to the "memory usage" in the android settings under "Developer Options" -> "Running Services". These values appear to be totally different as i watch them in real time. Does the "Memory Monitor" in Android Studio disclude the memory usage from services attached to the app? If so is there a way to view the memory usage for my Service in Android Studio or another tool that will help me track down Memory leaks?

I am already utilizing Leak Canary but it seems that Leak Canary is not catching leaks in my service.

Answer (score 0):

I'd ask for code but sounds that'll be alot.
B4 using tools i'd suggest you examine your code and try to evaluate where your leaks are coming from, have a read [here](https://techbeacon.com/what-you-need-know-about-android-app-memory-leaks) to understand more who to approach that.